# listview with section header android

Tags: android

Is it possible in android listview -> Headerbar(section) not scroll untill the list of that section not scroll. Like as iphone tableview. I used section listview but i want like this iphone tableview. is it any possiblities for that. Thanks.

Comment: do you expect that every endroid develioper know how iphone tableview looks like ??? please share screen you want to draw .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This project should help you:
http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/

Answer (score 3):

It is also helpful.... http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Here is a sample image from the library for those more visual:
[image]

Comment: I added a visual example from the library with the hopes of helping out more visually-oriented folks.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/