# listview with title group

Tags: android, android-listview

anyone know how to do a listview which looks like this? i can't make list view with title group (my listview include Image view and 2 TextView for evry item) , help me please

example:

---

asia(title group)

---

china-map(Imageview) china

japan-map(imageViw) japan

---

europe (tiltle group)

---

france-map(ImageView)  france

.
.
.

Comment: Fairly similar to this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507248/group-similar-rows-in-listview-based-on-their-content/23855234)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're referring to as "title group" is commonly called section headers. You'll find a lot of questions about this on here. Here are some related questions (some from the related section on the right...) with useful answers:

- [listview with section header android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788680/listview-with-section-header-android)
- [group similar rows in listview based on their content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507248/group-similar-rows-in-listview-based-on-their-content)